# stop UISearchDisplay Controller from resigning first responder Keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a search display controller.  If the user scrolls the table view of the search display controller after entering text into the search text field, the keyboard disappears because the search display controller is resigning first responder.  Is there a way to keep the keyboard there while scrolling is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `UISearchBar` a [delegate](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2Fuikit%2Freference%2FUISearchBarDelegate_Protocol%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=KfyHTYP-G4zmsQP-0viQDA&usg=AFQjCNFvi3wh4UUH51fVmJMiTL0G4XoLwQ) (perhaps the same object that is the delegate of your `UISearchDisplayController`) and implement [`searchBarShouldEndEditing:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007530-CH3-SW10) to return `NO` in the circumstances that you do not want it to resign (for example, when `mySearchDispController.searchResultsTableView.dragging` is `YES`).